# Como ocultar opciones de menú con MVC y PHP a cliente?

Tags: php, mvc

Agradezco me ayuden por favor , con la siguiente dificultad:

En el proyecto que estoy realizando necesitaba que el cliente  se registrara y que creara su contraseña desde el sitio web, para que pudiera ingresar.

La tabla cliente, que utilizo en la base de datos para el registro y el login del cliente, tiene un campo predeterminado llamado rol que cuando el cliente se registra siempre le  introduce el numero 2 en el campo y así logro que  no se pueda clasificar como administrador u orto tipo de usuario en el momento que se registra.

El problema surge cuando quiero ocultar de la barra de menú algunas opciones que deseo que el cliente no visualice, para lograrlo cree una session en el controlador que traiga el dato del campo "rol" predeterminado en la tabla cliente, y en el script de menú  le pongo una condición if para que ese rol solo vea una parte del menú pero no funciona, vi en algunas consultas que incluso se sugiere dentro el condicional el HTML del menú o barra lateral pero a mi no me permite se altera el código HTML. a continuación envió el código para que por favor me puedan ayudar.

```
<?php

Class ControladorUsuarios{
    
/////***ingreso cliente */
static public function ctrIngresoCliente(){
    if(isset($_POST["ClieNumeroDocumento"])){
      
        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/' , $_POST["ClieNumeroDocumento"]) &&
           preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/' , $_POST["ClieCreaPassword"])){
            $tabla ="cliente"; 
            $item ="ClieNumeroDocumento"; 
            $valor = $_POST["ClieNumeroDocumento"];
            $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarCliente($tabla, $item, $valor);
            if($respuesta["ClieNumeroDocumento"] ==$_POST["ClieNumeroDocumento"] && $respuesta["ClieCreaPassword"] == $_POST["ClieCreaPassword"]){
                $_SESSION["iniciarSesion"] = "ok";
                $_SESSION['rol'] = $respuesta["id_rol_clie"];
               
                echo '<script>
                window.location ="inicio";                    
                </script>';
            }else{
                echo '<script>
                swal({
                    type: "error",
                    title: "¡Los datos ingresados son incorrectos por favor intente nuevamente!",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                    closeOnConfirm:false
                }).then(function(result){
                    if(result.value){                       
                        window.location = "usuarios";
                    }
                });         
            </script>';
            }

           }
    }
}

}
?>
```

////script menu.php

```
  <?php
session_start();
?>

<aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
      <ul class="sidebar-menu">

      <?php if($_SESSION['rol']== 2 ):?>
          <li class="active">
              <a href="inicio">
                  <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                  <span>Inicio</span>
              </a>
          </li>
                    <li>
              <a href="usuarios">
                  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                  <span>Usuarios</span>
              </a>
          </li>
     

          <li>
              <a href="agenda">
                  <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                  <span>Agenda de servicios</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="servicios">
                  <i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>
                  <span>Administrar Servicios</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="clientes">
                  <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                  <span>Clientes</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i>
                  <span>Ventas</span>
                  <span class="pull-rigth-container">
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull"></i>
                  </span>
              </a> 
                     
        <?php endif;?>   
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                  <li>
                      <a href="ventas">
                          <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                          <span>Administrar venta</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="crear-venta">
                          <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                          <span>Crear Venta</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="reportes">
                          <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                          <span>Reporte de ventas</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>

              </ul>
          </li>

      </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
```

Comment: El código debe ir como texto, no como imagen. Es complicado de ver/analizar/reproducir para hacer pruebas cuando pones código en imagen. Igualmente, se agradece el uso del punto y aparte en la redacción. Por favor pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: @A. Cedano gracias por las observaciones.

Answer (score 0):

podrias realizar una validacion en el encabezado de cada vista php.

```php
// un codigo similar a esto deberias implementar en las vistas para que no se 
// salte la url
session_start();
if ( $_SESSION['logged'] ){
// Donde la variable de session logged deberia ser llenada
  //en el formulario de registro o de login

   // Ok esta registrado pero que rol posse?
 
    if ( $_SESSION['rol'] == 1 ) {
       // de igual manera rol deberias llenar cuando se logea
      //renderizar vista dependiendo de como manejes los roles
     }
}else{
   // redireccionas al login para registrarse o loggearse 
   // o muestas una vista generica
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, queria saber si de casualidad sabes como puedo ocultar del menu algunas opciones ya que me redirecciona al menu indicado pero no me deja ocultar el menu para que el cliente no lo visualice.

Comment: podes manipularlos con jquery supongo que deberias funcionar